# How to convert Uint8List to Float32List to List<double> in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using Dart's `typed_data` library together with `flutter_bluetooth_serial`. One of the latter's limitation is it can only read data in `Uint8List` format. However, I need to send a bunch of single-precision floating-point numbers (specifically from another microcontroller). I can send the data from the microcontroller to Flutter but the latter can't just decode the Uint8List well. I'm not sure if it is a bug in the library or I'm missing something in my code. Shown below is the snippet of the code which aims to convert `intBytes` to `List<double>`

```
Uint8List intBytes = Uint8List.fromList([63, 158, 184, 82,]);
List<double> floatList = intBytes.buffer.asFloat32List().toList();
```

The `intBytes` variable represents a four-byte single-precision number (1.24...) which is declared with an array of 8-bit integers. However floatBytes can't seem to get the correct value from the said array even after viewing the buffer as a list of float.
If I try to view the type of value from the first element with the following code

```
print(doubleList[0].runtimeType);
```

It reads it as an `int` data type but I was expecting a `double`

Comment: Try use `double.tryParse()`.

Comment: Where will I parse it? I'm not really getting the correct value from the list. For example in the code snippet, the first element's value will be `396464455680`; an integer value very far from the floating point value of `1.24...`

Answer (score 3):

From your comment:

> the first element's value will be `396464455680`; an integer value very far from the floating point value of `1.24...`

`396464455680` is a correct interpretation for a little-endian representation for a byte sequence `63`, `158`, `184`, `82`. You apparently assume that it will be interpreted as a big-endian single-precision floating point value, but IEEE-754 does not specify endianness. If you reverse the bytes, you will get `1.2400000095367432` on a little-endian system:

```dart
  Uint8List intBytes = Uint8List.fromList([63, 158, 184, 82].reversed.toList());
  List<double> floatList = intBytes.buffer.asFloat32List();
  print(floatList);
```

(Incidentally, `Float32List` derives from `List<double>`, so you do not need the extra `.toList()` call.)

Alternatively, you can use [`ByteData.getFloat32`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-typed_data/ByteData/getFloat32.html) to parse bytes with a specified endianness:

```dart
  Uint8List intBytes = Uint8List.fromList([63, 158, 184, 82]);
  ByteData byteData = intBytes.buffer.asByteData();
  List<double> floatList = [
    for (var offset = 0; offset < intBytes.length; offset += 4)
      byteData.getFloat32(offset, Endian.big),
  ];
  print(floatList);
```

Note that using `ByteData.getFloat32` would be more robust than reordering bytes yourself since it'd make your code agnostic to the endianness of the platform you're running on.

Regarding:

> ```dart
> print(doubleList[0].runtimeType);
> ```
>
> It reads it as an `int` data type but I was expecting a `double`

Presuming that you mean `floatList` (`doubleList` is not defined in your example), if you run that code in the Dart VM, `double` should be printed.

If, however, you run that code in a web browser (e.g. with DartPad or with Flutter for the Web), `int` will be printed.  As a simpler example, running:

```dart
  double d = 1.0;
  print(d.runtimeType);
```

in DartPad also will print `int`.  On the web, Dart transpiles to JavaScript, and for efficiency, Dart directly uses some JavaScript primitives.  JavaScript does not distinguish between integer and floating-point types; *all* numbers are double-precision floating point values.  It therefore isn't surprising that type information gets lost in the roundtrip.

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful response. Just one more question. What is the default endianness with `typed_data` library? If I'm getting floating-point data from an Arduino device (which is represents floats in little-endian by default), do I need to create a new function to deal with the conversion or the library already has a feature to deal with such case?

Comment: Unfortunately, using the buffer property doesn't work. Example in this code,
`
ByteData byteData = data.buffer.asByteData();
print(data.sublist(0, 4));
print(byteData.getUint8(0));
print(byteData.getUint8(1));
print(byteData.getUint8(2));
print(byteData.getUint8(3));
`
The contents of the latter three doesn't change whenever data is updated. The length in bytes also increases when I try to use buffer (I'm not sure why)

Comment: I expect that `ByteBuffer.as...` functions internally do the equivalent of a C++ `reinterpret_cast` and would use the platform's native endianness.  The `ByteData.get...` functions meanwhile *parse* bytes, and by default they parse as big-endian.

Comment: I don't understand your other problem.  It seems like a separate issue and that deserves its own question with specific reproduction steps.